# How to predict the accuracy of input data after training a neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

The essence of the problem: I wanted to understand the simplest neural network using a ready-made example from the Internet. I trained it, and then I don't understand how to test its validity on the input data of a conditional user. I found functions for model on the Internet: predict(), save(), loaded_model(). If save() and loaded_model() turned out and the folder '16_model' was created, then errors are thrown from predict(). Please tell me how to use it or how to test the neural network on input, and not on test data.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(2)

dataset = numpy.loadtxt("diabet.csv", delimiter=",")
X, Y = dataset[:,0:8], dataset[:,8]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, epochs = 100, batch_size=10)

scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)
#model.save('16_model')
#model_loaded = keras.models.load_model('16_model')
print("\n%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

Comment: You can just call evaluate on different data. Right now you run it on the same data you trained it on. Just assign X_Test, Y_Test = test_dataset[:,0:8], test_dataset[:,8] and use it in model.evaluate oder model.predict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the dataset into `training` and `testing` part as below, and use those `training set` to train the model and `test dataset` to evaluate the model:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
dataset =pd.read_csv("/content/../diabetes.csv")#, delimiter=",")
dataset.head()
X = dataset.drop('Outcome', 1)
y = dataset['Outcome']
Y.shape

train_X, test_X, train_Y, test_Y=train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)
train_X.shape
```

Then after defining and training the model with `train dataset`, you can evaluate the model with `test dataset`.

```
model_loss, model_acc = model.evaluate(test_X, test_Y)

print("Model Accuracy", model_acc*100)
model.save('16_model')
model_loaded = keras.models.load_model('16_model')
```

Output:

```
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.5637 - accuracy: 0.7208
Model Accuracy 72.07792401313782
INFO:tensorflow:Assets written to: 16_model/assets
```

Now evaluating the model again after saving and loading back the same model which shows same accuracy as before of saving the model.

```
model_loss, model_acc = model_loaded.evaluate(test_X, test_Y)
```

Output:

```
5/5 [==============================] - 0s 3ms/step - loss: 0.5637 - accuracy: 0.7208
```

**Here is Prediction Part:**

(This will show all the value within the range 0 to 1 due to `sigmoid` function used for binary classification)

```
pred=model_loaded.predict(train_X[:2])
print(pred))
```

Output:

```
[[0.925119  ]
 [0.45006576]]
```

All Values from <0.5 will come under class 0 and rest all will be assumed as class 1.

```
for p in pred:
    if p>=.5:
        pred_class=1
    else:
        pred_class=0
    print(pred_class)
```

Output:

```
1
0
```

You can verify this prediction with actual label:

```
train_Y[:2]
```

Output:

```
369    1
653    0
Name: Outcome, dtype: int64
```